# Generate Presigned URL to upload file to s3 bucket - generated URL failing on PUT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to generate a presigned URL to upload a file to an S3 bucket. The URL generated VIA lambda, throws the error: SignatureDoesNotMatch - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

When I execute the code on my local IDE, the generated URL works fine for upload.

I'm not sure what I'm missing and how to resolve this.

```py
def signed_url(): #My code on IDE - below code is placed under lambda_handler on aws lambda

    region = "us-east-1"
    bucket_name = "########"
    aws_s3_access_key_id = "########"
    aws_s3_secret_access_key = "########"
    expiration = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
    
    my_config = Config(
    region_name = region,
    signature_version = 'v4'
    )
    
    s3_client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=aws_s3_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_s3_secret_access_key,
    config=my_config
    )
    
    upload_key = uuid.uuid4().hex

    put_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
                ClientMethod='put_object',
                Params={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': upload_key},
                ExpiresIn=3600,
                HttpMethod='PUT'
            )
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'uuid4': upload_key,
        "upload_url": urllib.parse.unquote(put_url),
        "url_raw": put_url
    }
```

Code used on Lambda:

```py
import boto3
import datetime
import uuid
import urllib.parse
from botocore.config import Config
import config_file

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    expiration = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
    
    my_config = Config(
    region_name = config_file.region,
    signature_version = 'v4'
    )
    
    s3_client = boto3.client(
    config_file.service_s3,
    aws_access_key_id = config_file.aws_s3_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key = config_file.aws_s3_secret_access_key,
    config = my_config
    )
    
    upload_key = uuid.uuid4().hex

    put_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
                ClientMethod='put_object',
                Params={'Bucket': config_file.bucket_name, 'Key': upload_key},
                ExpiresIn=3600,
                HttpMethod='PUT'
            )
            
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'uuid4': upload_key,
        "upload_url": urllib.parse.unquote(put_url),
        "url_raw": put_url
    }
```

Comment: Just checking... I see that you are hard-coding the Access Key and Secret Key. Is this so that you can use permanent (long-lived) credentials rather than signing with the temporary credentials assigned to the AWS Lambda function?

Comment: The code on top is specifically for running on my local IDE. I'm using the temp credentials assigned to the lambda on AWS.

Comment: Well, that could lead to a problem... When a pre-signed URL is generated, it creates a hashed signature using the credentials provided at the time (which would be temporary credentials from the IAM Role assigned to the AWS Lambda function). When a pre-signed URL is used, the Access Key is included in the URL and the signature is verified by using the associated Secret Key. If the credentials used to generate the pre-signed URL are no longer valid, then the pre-signed URL will no longer be valid (because it is using those keys). This _might_ be causing your problem.

Comment: Please show the _actual_ code you are using in the AWS Lambda function.

Comment: Okay, I just tried using permanent credentials; I'm still getting the same error. --SignatureDoesNotMatch

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue, the culprit was `signature_version = 'v4'`.
for some reason, when you pass the value as v4 on lambda it wasn't generating the right auth signature. Replacing it with s3v4 worked fine.

I would appreciate if someone could explain why this is the case. As using v4 on my local IDE worked fine.

Comment: The AWS provided Lambda Execution Environment is using a rather old version of boto3/botocore, and you've run into a bug that was fixed in boto3-1.25.0/botocore-1.28.5, so you saw the correct behavior with a local copy that was updated at least after Apr 25, 2022, and the incorrect behavior on Lambda.